What is the purpose of notfiyRewardAmount for staking contract?
Video from 7:40 doesn't explain clearly on how notfiyRewardAmount: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ-IRzCYSXI
Why do we need the owner to call it? Doesn't that contract already holds the amount of rewards?
Can anyone prove the math?
